# Is the topological entropy time-reversal invariant?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

It seems that the question is sufficiently self-explanatory.  Will add details if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, **when the dynamics is a homeomorphism**. This is a simple exercise since a family of sets is a cover if and only if its image or preimage (under a homeomorphism!) is a cover.

However, in case you are talking about the topological entropy on a noncompact set, in general **it is not true** even if the dynamics is invertible. At some point it was introduced the notion of *two-sided topological entropy* for which what you ask holds for any noncompact set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer with clear explanation :)